# Cython Optimization of Numpy for Loop

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, cython

I am new to cython and have the following code for a numpy for loop that I am trying to optimize. So far, this Cython code isn't much faster than the numpy for loop.

```
# cython: infer_types = True
import numpy as np
cimport numpy

DTYPE = np.double

def hdcfTransfomation(scanData):
    cdef Py_ssize_t Position
    scanLength = scanData.shape[0]
    hdcfFunction_np = np.zeros(scanLength, dtype = DTYPE)
    cdef double [::1] hdcfFunction = hdcfFunction_np

    for position in range(scanLength - 1):
        topShift = scanData[1 + position:]
        bottomShift = scanData[:-(position + 1)]
        arrayDiff = np.subtract(topShift, bottomShift)
        arraySquared = np.square(arrayDiff)
        arrayMean = np.mean(arraySquared, axis = 0)
        hdcfFunction[position] = arrayMean
    return hdcfFunction
```

I know that using C math library functions would be more ideal than calling back into the numpy language (subtract, square, mean), but I am not sure where I can find a list of functions that can be called in this manner.

I have been trying to figure out ways to optimize this code by using different types, ect. but nothing is providing the performance that I think is possible with a fully optimized implementation of Cython.

Here is a working example of the numpy for-loop:

```
def hdcfTransfomation(scanData):
    scanLength = scanData.shape[0]
    hdcfFunction = np.zeros(scanLength)

    for position in range(scanLength - 1):
        topShift = scanData[1 + position:]
        bottomShift = scanData[:-(position + 1)]
        arrayDiff = np.subtract(topShift, bottomShift)
        arraySquared = np.square(arrayDiff)
        arrayMean = np.mean(arraySquared, axis = 0)
        hdcfFunction[position] = arrayMean
    return hdcfFunction

scanDataArray = np.random.rand(80000, 1)
transformedScan = hdcfTransformed(scanDataArray)
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's any need for a `for` loop, just apply the shifts and operations to a 2D array. `hdcfFunction_np` can just be a copy of the original array and then apply the changes in-place

Comment: have you tried `cdef int position` before the `for loop`?

Comment: Do you know where the most time in your calculation is spent? I would guess it is somewhere inside of the numpy-functions. Cythonizing calls of these functions will not help much...

Comment: If the performance is your main goal, I would recommend you to implement your code in pure C, compile it into a dynamic library (.dll or .so). In Python you can import it using `ctypes`. I researched, it's much faster than Cythonization on ordinary examples, but I'm not fully sure in case of `numpy`. I think you can try it at least.

Comment: What is the usual shape of scanData? This function can definitely run quite a lot faster, but may need a rewrite.

Comment: The normal shape of the scanData is an array that generally has a shape of (1, 80000)

Comment: In this case scanLength - 1 would be zero and so would be the output of your function. Are you sure that it is not (80000) -> scanData.shape[0]==80000 instead of 1? Anyway please always provide a full working example. This includes also some sample data eg. scanData=np.random.rand(80_000).

Comment: @max9111, you are correct, I meant (80000, 1)! Thank you. The question has been updated to include a working example for the numpy for loop.

Comment: @Adrian Stalnaker I have added a naive GPU implementation (actually the first one I have ever made). On resonable fast GPUs this might outperform the CPU implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always provide as much informations as possible (some example data, Python/Cython Version, Compiler Version/Settings and CPU Model.

Without that it is quite hard to compare any timings. For example this problem benefits quite well from SIMD-vectorization. It will make quite a difference which compiler you use or if you want to redistribute a compiled version which should also run on low-end or quite old CPUS (eg. no AVX).

I am not very familiar with Cython, but I think your main problem is the missing declaration for `scanData`. Maybe the C-Compiler needs additional flags like `march=native`, but the real syntax is compiler dependend. I am am also not sure how Cython or the C-compiler optimizes this part:

```
    arrayDiff = np.subtract(topShift, bottomShift)
    arraySquared = np.square(arrayDiff)
    arrayMean = np.mean(arraySquared, axis = 0)
```

If that loops (all vectorized commands are actually loops) are not joined, but intead there are temporary arryas like in pure Python created, this will slow down the code. It will be a good idea to create a 1D array first. (eg. `scanData=scanData[::1]`

As said I am not that familliar with Cython, I tried what is possible with Numba. At least it shows what should also be possible with a resonable good Cython implementation.

**Maybe easier to otimize for the compiler**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,error_model='numpy',parallel=True)
#scanData is a 1D-array here
def hdcfTransfomation(scanData):
  scanLength = scanData.shape[0]
  hdcfFunction = np.zeros(scanLength, dtype = scanData.dtype)

  for position in nb.prange(scanLength - 1):
    topShift = scanData[1 + position:]
    bottomShift = scanData[:scanData.shape[0]-(position + 1)]
    sum=0.
    jj=0
    for i in range(scanLength-(position + 1)):
      jj+=1
      sum+=(topShift[i]-bottomShift[i])**2

    hdcfFunction[position] = sum/jj
  return hdcfFunction
```

I also used parallelization here, because the problem is embarrassingly parallel. At least with a size of 80_000 and Numba it doesn't matter if you use a slightly modified version of your code (1D-array), or the code above.

**Timings**

```
#Quadcore Core i7-4th gen,Numba 0.4dev,Python 3.6
scanData=np.random.rand(80_000)
#The first call to the function isn't measured (compilation overhead),but the following calls.

Pure Python:           5900ms
Numba single-threaded: 947ms
Numba parallel:        260ms
```

Especially for larger arrays than `np.random.rand(80_000)` there may be better aproaches (loop tilling for better cache usage), but for this size that should be more or less OK (At least it fits in the L3-cache)

**Naive GPU Implementation**

```
from numba import cuda, float32
@cuda.jit('void(float32[:], float32[:])')
def hdcfTransfomation_gpu(scanData,out_data):
  scanLength = scanData.shape[0]
  position = cuda.grid(1)

  if position < scanLength - 1:
    sum= float32(0.)
    offset=1 + position
    for i in range(scanLength-offset):
      sum+=(scanData[i+offset]-scanData[i])**2
      out_data[position] = sum/(scanLength-offset)

hdcfTransfomation_gpu[scanData.shape[0]//64,64](scanData,res_3)
```

This gives about 400ms on a GT640 (float32) and 970ms (float64). For a good implemenation [shared arrays](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/examples.html) should be considered.

Comment: On my machine the loop in pure python takes about 8 seconds. With the cython function it takes about 4 seconds. This numba implementation gets it down to about 1.5 seconds, not bad!

Comment: @Adrian Stalnaker 1.5s are really slow. Have you called the function once (compilation overhead of about 1.xs on the first call) before taking the timings? Which CPU?

Comment: That 1.5 seconds was based on the second call of the function. My machine has 4 CPUs that it is using for this problem. I also have a decent GPU that I could use but I can't figure out how to get a Numba working with my GPU, any guidance on that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `cython` aside, does this do the same thing as your current code but without a `for` loop? We can tighten it up and correct for inaccuracies, but the first port of call is to try apply operations in numpy to 2D arrays before turning to `cython` for `for` loops. It's too long to put in a comment.

```
import numpy as np

# Setup
arr = np.random.choice(np.arange(10), 100).reshape(10, 10)

top_shift = arr[:, :-1]
bottom_shift = arr[:, 1:]
arr_diff = top_shift - bottom_shift
arr_squared = np.square(arr_diff)
arr_mean = arr_squared.mean(axis=1)
```